# React.js/JS, how to access file ex e.target.value[0] (avoid creating separate useState)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects, console.log

I want to avoid creating many (element setElement =useState) I use (formData setFormData  = useState) as below and inside it there are some elements.

I can access e.target.value[0] 'file' only in the below 2nd example but how to access it in the 1st example. To be precise I want the onChange on below passport_photo form to access the e.target.value[0] to give me the results as the 2nd example console.log

1st example ;

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setAlert } from '../actions/alert';
import './ApplicationForm.css';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import ExpandLessIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import { IconButton } from '@mui/material';



function ApplicationForm({ setAlert }) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState (false);

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
     pasport_number: '', passport_photo: (null)
  });

  const { pasport_number, passport_photo } = formData;

  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  console.log (formData);
  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      let dataForm = new FormData();

      dataForm.append('pasport_number',pasport_number)
      
      if(passport_photo !== null) {
        dataForm.append('passport_photo', passport_photo)
      }
      await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/application-form/`,
        data: dataForm,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' 
        }

        })
      .then(_res => console.log(_res))
      .catch(_err => {
          setAlert('Error with Sending Application', 'error');
      })
  };

  return (
        <div className='applicationForm'>
            <div className='wrapper'>
                    <Helmet>
                        <title>Prosperity - Visa Application Form</title>
                        <meta
                            name='description'
                            content='Filling Application Form '
                        />
                    </Helmet>
                <div className='applicationForm__wrapper'>
                    <h1 className='applicationForm__title'>Application Form</h1>
                    <hr className='appform__hr'/>
                    <form className='applicationForm__form' onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)} enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div className='form__wrap'>
    
                            <hr className='appform__hr'/>

                            <p className='passport__section__title'>Enter or Import Passport Details</p>
                            <div className='input_grp'>
                                <div className='input_wrap input_wrap__bt'>
                                    <p className='expand__p'>Enter Passport details</p>
                                    <IconButton onClick={()=> setShow(true)}>
                                        <ExpandMoreIcon className='Expand__bt'/>
                                    </IconButton>
                                    <IconButton onClick={()=> setShow(false)}>
                                        <ExpandLessIcon className='Expand__less__bt'/>
                                    </IconButton>
                                </div>
                                <div className='input_wrap input_wrap__bt import__passport'>
                                    <label className='applicationForm__form__label' htmlFor='passport_photo'>Import Passport Image</label>
                                    <input 
                                        className='input__for__two import__passport' 
                                        name='passport_photo' 
                                        type='file' 
                                        accept='image/*,.pdf'
                                        placeholder='Import Passport' 
                                        onChange={e => onChange(e)} 
                                        value={passport_photo} 
                                        required 
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            { show?
                                <>

                                <div className='input_grp'>
                                    <div className='form__wrap'>
                                        <label className='applicationForm__form__label' htmlFor='pasport_number'>Passport Number</label>
                                        <input 
                                            className='applicationForm__form__input input__for__two' 
                                            name='pasport_number' 
                                            type='text' 
                                            placeholder='Passport Number' 
                                            onChange={e => onChange(e)} 
                                            value={pasport_number} 
                                            required 
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </>
                                :null
                            }
                            <hr className='appform__hr'/>
                            <button className='contact__form__button' htmltype='submit'>Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  )
}

export default connect(null, { setAlert })(ApplicationForm);
```

console.log(formData) ;

```
{pasport_number: 'test', passport_photo: 'C:\\fakepath\\signature.jpg'}
pasport_number: "test"
passport_photo: "C:\\fakepath\\signature.jpg"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

2nd example ;

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setAlert } from '../actions/alert';
import './ApplicationForm.css';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import ExpandLessIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import { IconButton } from '@mui/material';



function ApplicationForm({ setAlert }) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState (false);

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
     pasport_number: ''
  });

  const [passport_photo, setPassport_photo] = useState(null)

  const { pasport_number } = formData;

  const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  console.log (passport_photo);
  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      let dataForm = new FormData();

      dataForm.append('pasport_number',pasport_number)
      
      if(passport_photo !== null) {
        dataForm.append('passport_photo', passport_photo)
      }
      await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/application-form/`,
        data: dataForm,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' 
        }

        })
      .then(_res => console.log(_res))
      .catch(_err => {
          setAlert('Error with Sending Application', 'error');
      })
  };

  return (
        <div className='applicationForm'>
            <div className='wrapper'>
                    <Helmet>
                        <title>Prosperity - Visa Application Form</title>
                        <meta
                            name='description'
                            content='Filling Application Form '
                        />
                    </Helmet>
                <div className='applicationForm__wrapper'>
                    <h1 className='applicationForm__title'>Application Form</h1>
                    <hr className='appform__hr'/>
                    <form className='applicationForm__form' onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)} enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div className='form__wrap'>
    
                            <hr className='appform__hr'/>

                            <p className='passport__section__title'>Enter or Import Passport Details</p>
                            <div className='input_grp'>
                                <div className='input_wrap input_wrap__bt'>
                                    <p className='expand__p'>Enter Passport details</p>
                                    <IconButton onClick={()=> setShow(true)}>
                                        <ExpandMoreIcon className='Expand__bt'/>
                                    </IconButton>
                                    <IconButton onClick={()=> setShow(false)}>
                                        <ExpandLessIcon className='Expand__less__bt'/>
                                    </IconButton>
                                </div>
                                <div className='input_wrap input_wrap__bt import__passport'>
                                    <label className='applicationForm__form__label' htmlFor='passport_photo'>Import Passport Image</label>
                                    <input 
                                        className='input__for__two import__passport' 
                                        name='passport_photo' 
                                        type='file' 
                                        accept='image/*,.pdf'
                                        placeholder='Import Passport' 
                                        onChange={(e)=>setPassport_photo(e.target.files[0])}
                                        required 
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            { show?
                                <>

                                <div className='input_grp'>
                                    <div className='form__wrap'>
                                        <label className='applicationForm__form__label' htmlFor='pasport_number'>Passport Number</label>
                                        <input 
                                            className='applicationForm__form__input input__for__two' 
                                            name='pasport_number' 
                                            type='text' 
                                            placeholder='Passport Number' 
                                            onChange={e => onChange(e)} 
                                            value={pasport_number} 
                                            required 
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </>
                                :null
                            }
                            <hr className='appform__hr'/>
                            <button className='contact__form__button' htmltype='submit'>Send</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  )
}

export default connect(null, { setAlert })(ApplicationForm);
```

2nd example console.log(passport_photo) ;

```
File {name: 'signature.jpg', lastModified: 1612947480000, lastModifiedDate: Wed Feb 10 2021 09:58:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 536092, …}
lastModified: 1612947480000
lastModifiedDate: Wed Feb 10 2021 09:58:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}
name: "signature.jpg"
size: 536092
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
[[Prototype]]: File
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you want to use same state variable for both `formData` and `passport_photo`, you need to have different `onChange` method for handling `passport_photo` file upload.

```
<input
  className="input__for__two import__passport"
  name="passport_photo"
  type="file"
  accept="image/*,.pdf"
  placeholder="Import Passport"
  onChange={(e) => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0] })}
  required
/>
```

Comment: Many thanks! this saved me a lot of time. it works well now. Could you please share the other onChange method to handle passport file upload?

Comment: @Moammer the different `onChange` method I have already given in the answer.

Comment: Hi Aditya, Many thanks for your help. I was a bit confused why passport_photo isn't mentioned in the onChange methode even though its state is changed perfectly as expected. Just to understand what's going on in case I added other input fields to upload other documents.